# Linking accounts in Dungeon hunter 5?

Tags: dungeon-hunter

I have played DH5 on Windows 10 PC. But I recently bought an android device and downloaded DH5 on it. I want my old character and stats on android too, but when I go to link devices on PC win DH5 app, it shows no code and keeps on saying make sure you are connected with Facebook on both accounts, which I am but of no use. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same situation. I do not have a solution yet, but I've contacted their customer care by email. This is the recommended method for resolution of this conflict. You can access the customer care only from in-game. Login, click the "G" icon on top left, and from there click on Customer Care.